# how to access ThreadMx of com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean on jenkins , junit test

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

I have a junit test cases with a class to monitor allocated bytes for a thread. From eclipse I was able to get the valid results. However  in jenkins it's not working since com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean is not provided.

here's my code

`((com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean)ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()).getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId())))`

How can get hold of com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean  for I need to retrieve getThreadAllocatedBytes() ? how can i set the sun/oracle Vm right?

java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.management.ThreadImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper error description. You might want to elaborate on that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that the execution was somewhat running on a jvm that doesn't support ThreadMXBean . In my ant configuration I added fork to a new thread. It worked great.

Answer (score 5):

Code in `com.sun.*` packages are only available to Sun/Oracle JVMs, [other implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) may not have access to these proprietary classes which aren't part of the official JDK.  Essentially, Sun added some additional functionality onto `ThreadMXBean` (and confusingly didn't change the name) but didn't want to mandate that all JVM implementations similarly implement this behavior.

Presumably Jenkins doesn't use (or yours is configured not to) Oracle's JVM.  Wild guess, but it may be using JRockit.

Generally speaking, you should implement code assuming `com.sun.*` classes are not available by default, and should check at runtime if in fact they are.  For example, here's a snippet of how I'm currently handling the `ThreadMXBean` issue:

```
private static boolean enableBeanInspection = true;
private ThreadMXBean tBean = null;
private com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean sunBean = null;

public ThreadInspector() {
    // Ensure beans are null if we can't / don't want to use them
    if(enableBeanInspection) {
        tBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        if(tBean instanceof com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean) { 
            sunBean = (com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean)tBean;
        }

        if(tBean.isThreadCpuTimeSupported()) {
            if(!tBean.isThreadCpuTimeEnabled()) {
                tBean.setThreadCpuTimeEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            tBean = null;
        }

        if(sunBean != null && sunBean.isThreadAllocatedMemorySupported()) {
            if(!sunBean.isThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled()) {
                sunBean.setThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            sunBean = null;
        }
    }
}

protected long getThreadTime() {
    if(tBean != null) {
        return tBean.getThreadCpuTime(threadId);
    }
    return -1;
}

protected long getThreadMemory() {
    if(sunBean != null) {
        return sunBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(threadId);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This defensive assume-we-don't-have-beans pattern lets you safely get as much information as the JVM will allow.

Comment: This will fail on JVMs without com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean, because your class imports it. You need to use reflection instead to access that class :-(

Comment: Haha of course it would. I'll correct it when I'm at a computer.

Comment: Most JVMs used are either a distribution of OpenJDK which includes this class of Sun, or have different VM but bundle the classes of OpenJDK which includes this class (e.g. Eclipse J9)

Answer (score 0):

I did this just with

```
ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
```

without casting to itseft. Have you tried the same?

Comment: At somepoint i require to case it since com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean has .getThreadAllocatedBytes()

Comment: What classes were you importing in order to do that?  The `ThreadMXBean` your example uses is almost certainly [java.lang.managment.ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html), the question is regarding the child interface [com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html) which is often, but not always, the implementation that is returned from ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().